# Flexbox a href same display block?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm sorry, I speak a little English.

I try use a flexbox.

My HTML codes:

```
<div class="title">
    <div class="left-title">
        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
    </div>
    <div class="right-title">June 18, 2021</div>
</div>
```

My CSS codes:

```
.title {

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;

}

    .left-title {

        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;

    }

        .left-title a {

            line-height: 48px;
            background-color: green;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 0 1em;
            text-decoration: none;
            height: 48px;
            color: black;

        }

            .left-title a:hover {

                color: white;

            }

    .right-title {

        white-space: nowrap;
        line-height: 48px;
        padding: 0 1em;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;

    }
```

This is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/umkBs.jpg

I would like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq62i.jpg

I need a tag is full size (green background).

Edit: plus HTML codes for JHeth.

How to?

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow, could you also provide your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `flex-grow: 1` to `.left-title` to fill the entire remaining `.title`.
Add `display: block` to the `a` (otherwise it behaves like an inline element and does not fit to its parent).
Move `text-overflow: ellipsis` to the `a`.

```css
.title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.left-title {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* text-overflow: ellipsis; <-- You don't need this*/ 
  flex-grow: 1; /* <-- */
}

.left-title a {
  line-height: 48px;
  background-color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 48px;
  color: black;
  display: block; /* <-- */
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /* <-- */
  overflow: hidden; /* <-- */
}

.left-title a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.right-title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 48px;
  padding: 0 1em;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <div class="left-title">
    <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div class="right-title">June 18, 2021</div>
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div class="title">
  <div class="left-title">
    <a href="#">Long Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div class="right-title">June 18, 2021</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not perfect, please see the uploaded screenshot.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. can you describe it?

Comment: The second, the longer .title end: ... (I need the three dots)

Comment: Very nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: red;
  width:100%;
  line-height:48px;
}

.left-title {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
}

.left-title a {
   background-color:green;
display:block;
white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 1em;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.left-title a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.right-title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0 1em;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <div class="left-title">
    <a href="#">Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum fdsgdfg sdg dsfg sd fg s df g sdfg</a>
  </div>
  <div class="right-title">June 18, 2023333333</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dear Nikita TSB, Thanks.